# Отличия, принцип работы vector::reserve() и vector::capacity()

Tags: c++, vector

Пишу для себя реализацию контейнера vector. И не могу понять принцип работы и что вообще делают методи  vector::capacity() и vector::reserve(). Читал документацию, но ничего не понимаю.

Comment: [Читаем доку](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/) `std::vector::reserve` -- Request a change in capacity (меняет размер выделенной памяти)  `std::vector::capacity` -- Return size of allocated storage capacity (сообщает этот размер)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дело в том, что внутри вектора используется простой динамический массив (это должно быть очевидно, но я уточню все же), на который можно даже получить указатель через `vector:data()`. При этом вектор позволяет почти неограниченно добавлять данные в него (пока память не кончится). Как же он это делает? Также как и вы бы делали с динамическим массивом: запрашивает у ОС блок памяти большего размера, копирует туда все текущие данные, добавляет туда новые данные и освобождает старый блок памяти.

Но есть одна особенность: если память в текущем блоке закончилась и вы хотите еще добавить данные, он запрашивает новый блок памяти куда большего размера, чем необходимо (например в два раза больше, чем есть сейчас, а не N+1, где N это текущее количество элементов в векторе). Зачем? Представьте что вам надо добавлять в конец вектора много-много элементов в цикле. Представьте как медленно оно будет работать, если на каждой итерации придется заново перевыделять память на N+1 элементов, потом это все копировать еще, короче ужас. А если запросить сразу много памяти, то перевыделять память придется куда реже.

Тут конечно важно соблюсти меру, чтобы не было много неиспользуемой памяти. Я не знаю честно, по какой стратегии различные реализации вектора вычисляют размер памяти, который надо выделить, но мне видится так, что выделять каждый раз в 2 раза больше памяти, чем есть, это достаточно оптимально. GCC вроде так и [делает](http://ideone.com/jcsFwF).

Теперь непосредственно перейду к вопросу. `vector::capacity()` показывает, сколько элементов вектор может вместить без перевыделения памяти, тогда как `vector::size()` показывает, сколько элементов хранится в векторе в текущий момент. Понятно, что `vector::size()` будет меньше или равен `vector::capacity()`. `vector::reserve(size_type N)` же говорит вектору выделить достаточно памяти для хранения *минимум* N элементов, то есть эта функция изменяет `vector::capacity()`.

Comment: ну о том что там динамческний массив я знаю. То есть у меня в класе будет еще переменная `int capacity`. И если я использую в начале `vector::reserve()`, то `capacity` будет в два раза больше?

Comment: @Oleg_Hudyma учтите, что `vector::reserve(size_type N)` имеет аргумент, указывающий то количество элементов, для которого ему надо выделить память. сколько реально будет выделено памяти я не могу сказать, это надо проверять для каждого компилятора отдельно. Может быть выделено памяти как ровно под N элементов, так и под большее количество. Да и в начале нет смысла использовать `vector::reserve(size_type N)`, вы можете прямо в [конструкторе](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) вектора указать, под сколько элементов выделить памяти при создани ивектора.

Comment: @Oleg_Hudyma: С чего бы это вдруг `capacity` станет в два раза больше? `capacity` обычно растет именно до того значения, которое было указано в `reserve()`. `reserve()` для того и предназначен, чтобы управлять `capacity`. Откуда вы взяли "два раза больше"?

Comment: @AnT [не обязательно](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) "Note that the resulting vector capacity may be equal or greater than n", то есть я так понимаю в принципе `reserve()` может выделить больше места, чем указано в аргументе, если разработчики предусмотрели именно такую стратегию изменения размера вектора.

Comment: @Flowneee: Может, конечно. Но это скорее будут соображения какой-нибудь гранулярности (напр, "`capacity` всегда кратно 16" или "`capacity` - всегда степень двойки"), которую такой примитивной взаимосвязью, как "я делаю `reserve(20)`, значит `capacity` станет 40" не опишешь. Это скорее с `size` может существовать такая взаимосвязь - как только `size` достигает `capacity`, `capacity` увеличивается в 2 раза - одна из возможных стратегий.

Comment: @AnT ну тут я конечно с вами согласен

Comment: @Flowneee тогда в `vector` будет еще переменная `int capacity` и `int reserved` или reserved то самое что `int size`?

Comment: @Oleg_Hudyma вы не поняли. ФУНКЦИЯ `capacity()` просто возвращает ЗНАЧЕНИЕ некоторой внутренней переменной, хранящей объем выделенной памяти, назовем ее условно `__capacity`.  ФУНКЦИЯ `reserve(N)` перевыделяет память под N элементов, при этом устанавливая новое значение переменной `__capacity`. То же самое и с ФУНКЦИЕЙ `size()`: она просто возвращает значение некоторой внутренней переменной (условно `__size`), содержащей в себе реальное количество элементов

Comment: @Flowneee да я понял. Просто хотел узнать, есть ли для `capacity()` и `reserve()` отдельние переменние, с которими они работают. Теперь понял что оба метода работают с переменной `capacity`. Спасибо за помощь)